# Dynamic Page according to React-Redux state not updating rendered data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-dom

I want to build a one-page login system which renders different pages according to the state I set in the React-Redux store. The `render() {}` function isn't updating when the state of the store updates.

`App.js`

```
import React from 'react'

import store from './redux/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

// Route to Renderer.js below
import Renderer from './Renderer'

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={ store }>
                <Renderer page={store.getState().page} />
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

`Renderer.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

// Routes to my pages I plan to render
import Login from './routes/Login'
import About from './routes/About'
import Register from './routes/Register'

class Renderer extends Component {
    render() {
        let page = this.props.page
        let returned

        switch (page) {
            case 'About':
                returned = <About />
                break
            case 'Login':
                returned = <Login />
                break
            case 'Register':
                returned = <Register />
                break
            default:
                returned = <About />
        }

        return returned
    }
}

export default Renderer
```

I have a component linked to a Redux Action which changed the state of the `page` field. This isn't shown for simplicity sake. The change in the state is confirmed because the Redux Development Tools tells me that the state changed when I dispatch the actions to change the `page` Redux state. When I change the Redux state of the `page` field, the rendered page doesn't update and stays at the default page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing `page` as an implicit prop to `Renderer`, use `react-redux` connect in order to pass this prop to the component using a `mapStateToProps` function:

`Renderer.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

// Routes to my pages I plan to render
import Login from './routes/Login'
import About from './routes/About'
import Register from './routes/Register'

class Renderer extends Component {
    render() {
        let page = this.props.page
        let returned

        switch (page) {
            case 'About':
                returned = <About />
                break
            case 'Login':
                returned = <Login />
                break
            case 'Register':
                returned = <Register />
                break
            default:
                returned = <About />
        }

        return returned
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state)=>({
  page: state.page
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Renderer)
```

`App.js`

```
import React from 'react'

import store from './redux/store'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

// Route to Renderer.js below
import Renderer from './Renderer'

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={ store }>
              // remove the page prop here
                <Renderer />
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

By passing the page prop like this: 
`page={store.getState().page}` your `Renderer` component doesn't actually subscribe to store changes, so it will always return the initial `page` value.

The `react-redux` `connect` wrapper takes care of this subscription to the store - so your component will get an updated page value from the `Provider` on each store update.